# Spark Job Chaining using Azure Data Factory V1

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-factory

Suppose we have three spark jobs say S1,S2 and S3 .

I want to configure these two jobs in a way so that once S1 is complete successfully, then S2 should be invoked .
On the other hand ,if S1 is failed then S3 should be invoked .
How this can be done using Azure Data Factory V1 ?

Comment: If could be do easily in v2. Do you have any concern to use v2?

Comment: No concern as such , I started with v1 that is why was trying to check the documentation with ADF v1 .Could not find anything available in v1,in v2 already found events like "On Success","On Completion" etc .If there is none in v1 would definitely go ahead with v2 .Is there no such feature available in ADF V1 ?

Comment: V1 uses output dataset to drive the schedule. I think it is not easy. I would suggest you use v2. And v2 is also GA now. It has a more advanced UI as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use v2, this is [the v2 doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#activity-dependency) for activity dependency.